# Is it possible to access an external asset directory with the CakePHP Image helper?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

My CakePHP Folder Structure

```
   1. app / webroot / img
   2. cake
   3. vendors
   4. assets

<?php echo $html->image('cake_logo.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP'))?>
```

Is it possible to access my external **asset** directory with the CakePHP Image helper?

Comment: How can I change a Core Definition Constant?
Is this possible within my app and where should I do this? e.g. in the core.php of my app???

Comment: Constants are, by definition, immutable. To change it, you'd have to alter the source--not something I'd recommend in any, but the most extreme circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this, but I believe that Cake relies on the web server to serve up image assets by default. This would suggest that, no, you can't move your images outside of your web root and still use the HTML helper's `image()` method.

You can, however, use [media views](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1094/Media-Views) to send binary information to users. It works outside of the core helpers, but might meet your needs.

Comment: I added a RedirectMatch rule to the .htaccess in the webroot directory.
RedirectMatch /img/(.*) http://assets.example.com/img/$1

Comment: Hey, you added a _new_ web root. That's cheating. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to go up the directory by adding `../` at the front of image file as many times as it is necessary like this:

```
echo $html->image('../../special_assets_folder/cake_logo.png');
```

That worked for me in some cases.

Comment: No, that won't work. The Cake Image helper will output this:
 <img src="/img/../../special_assets_folder/cake_logo.png" />

Comment: What about `echo $html->image('/../../special_assets_folder/cake_logo.png');`? Notice - starting with slash.